# How to switch activities with fingers?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 7 activites and i want them to switch with finger to the right or to the left can you guys help me?

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static ImageButton bt_lb1, bt_lb2, bt_lb3, bt_combri, bt_tp, bt_dp, bt_cal;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    OnClickImageButtonListener();
}
public void OnClickImageButtonListener() {

    bt_lb1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img_bt_lb1);
    bt_lb1.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
    bt_lb2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img_bt_lb2);
    bt_lb2.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
    bt_lb3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img_bt_lb3);
    bt_lb3.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FourthActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
    bt_combri = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img_bt_combri);
    bt_combri.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FifthActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
    bt_tp = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img_bt_tp);
    bt_tp.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SeventhActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
    bt_dp = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img_bt_dp);
    bt_dp.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SixthActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
    bt_cal = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img_bt_cal);
    bt_cal.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EighthActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );

}
```

}

Comment: Use Fragments instead Acitivities. And in your case better use view pager with pager adapter which extends from FragmentsPagerAdapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use Fragments instead of Activities.

Start by creating 1 Activity containing a viewpager. Then use your 7 Fragments as pages within this viewpager.

A good tutorial how to implement the viewpager can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html).

Comment: Your link is broken bro can u send it again?

Answer (score 0):

Using ViewPager is the method for your case

https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: I dont want just to switch images. Atm i only have images on the activities but i will put some text there about each image.

Comment: This tutorial will help you regarding you problem

http://javapapers.com/android/android-image-slider-tutorial/